# Is $\arctan (\cos(x))$ periodic?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, examples-counterexamples, recreational-mathematics, periodic-functions

I know that $\arctan$ is not periodic. How can this be proved?

If you have a periodic function, within a non periodic function, does the overal function become non periodic, say for $\arctan(\cos(x))$, if we have $x+t$ where $t = 2\pi$ then $\arctan(\cos(x+t)) = \arctan(cos(x))$ which suggests it is periodic?

Please could someone provide a comprehensive method for solving this?

[Using an online calculator has given me a result that contradicts my intuition above.](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/function-periodicity-calculator/periodicity%20f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3Dtan%5E%7B-1%7D%5Cleft(cos%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)?or=input) Symbolab is flawed so I apologise, but I just wanted clarification. I have been racking my brain for ages. I dont think I’ll trust an online calculator again.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I believe you just proved that it is periodic.

Comment: problem is online calculators say it is not periodic so i am very confused

Comment: "arctan is not periodic, how can this be proved?" For that part show $\arctan x=\arctan y\implies x=y$.

Comment: You should've believed your instincts. Your logic is correct and the function is periodic. Which Web site says that it's not?

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/function-periodicity-calculator/periodicity%20f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3Dtan%5E%7B-1%7D%5Cleft(cos%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)?or=input

Comment: Something must be wrong with their calculator, because obviously  [this function](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/function-periodicity-calculator/periodicity%20f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3DSin%5Cleft(cos%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5Cright)?or=input) is periodic.

Comment: More generally, if $f(x)$ is periodic, with period $T$, and $g(x)$ is *any* function defined in the range of $f$, the $g(f(x))$ is periodic with period $T$.

Comment: Specifically, since $\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2\pi)$, you know that $\arctan[\cos(x)] = \arctan[\cos(x + 2\pi)].$  The period is then less than or equal to $(2\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as in the comments @eyeballfrog mentioned that you have already proven that it is periodic

Since for any periodic functions f(x), $\exists$ some $T$ such that $f(x+T)=f(x)$

As you said in your description, $f(x)=tan^{-1}[cos(x)]$ and $T=2\pi$, so therefore $tan^{-1}[cos(x)]$ is periodic

[image: ...]

If you aren't convinced, here's a graph of $tan^{-1}[cos(x)]$

Comment: that you so much, thats what my instincts said and what i got from looking at the graph.